# In the script the data is coming from server but not initialized into variables

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var _dateFormat = '';
        _dateFormat = '<%= WebUI.Models.WebConfigKeys.DateFormat %>';

        var dateArray = '<%= ViewData["CompareCollectionDateSvc"] %>';
        var enabledDays = new Array();
        enabledDays = dateArray.split(",");
        var _firstVal = enabledDays[0];
        var _LastVal = enabledDays[4];

        GetCalederLoad(_firstVal, _LastVal, _dateFormat);

        function GetCalederLoad(startDt, endDt, dtFormat) {
            if (dtFormat != undefined && dtFormat != "")
                dtFormat = dtFormat.toLowerCase();

            $("#drpNewCollectionDateSvc").datepicker({
                autoclose: true,
                clearBtn: true,
                startDate: startDt, // '(System.Web.Mvc.SelectList)(ViewData["CollectionDate"]).First();', //firstarrdate,
                endDate: endDt, // '(System.Web.Mvc.SelectList)(ViewData["CollectionDate"]).Last();',// lastarrdate,
                format: dtFormat,
                daysOfWeekDisabled: [0, 6],
                Default: false,
                beforeShowDay: function (Date) {
                    var curr_date = Date.toJSON().substring(0, 10);
                }
            });
        }

    });
</script>
```

In this script I am getting data from the server in `ViewData` or WebConfig but it is not getting set into other variables. I am getting an error:

> The Name "_dateformat" does not exist in the current context

Comment: Have you checked the actual source to ensure that the values from the server are being put in to your JS code correctly, and that they have valid values? It would be far more helpful putting the server output in your question.

Comment: Yes i am getting all the values from the server. I have accessed the value through hidden fields also.

Comment: Also note that you can omit the `new Array()` declaration and just do `var enabledDays = dateArray.split(',');`

Comment: Use developer tools to view your javascript code (F12 in most browsers)

Comment: This JavaScript is in the .ascx page and it is being rendered in User control on another page.

Comment: I have used developers tools also.

Comment: Can't you open that page and search the rendered output with developer tools? search for GetCalederLoad...

Comment: Or you can write 'debugger;' inside your script and reload

Comment: $(document).ready(function () {
        var _dateFormat = '';
        _dateFormat = 'MM-dd-yyyy';

        var dateArray = '07/05/2016,07/06/2016,07/07/2016,07/08/2016,07/11/2016';
        var enabledDays = new Array();
        enabledDays = dateArray.split(",");
        var _firstVal = enabledDays[0];
        var _LastVal = enabledDays[4];
             
    });
These are the values i am getting from server.Rest of the script is above

Comment: but as the variables are not getting initilized it is giving error.l

Comment: Why not just declare the values inside the function instead of onReady?

Comment: @Nikhil Does my answer work or not?

Answer (score 0):

Your output is the following:

```
var dateArray = '07/05/2016,07/06/2016,07/07/2016,07/08/2016,07/11/2016';
```

Then you can use the following:

```js
var _dateFormat = '';
//_dateFormat = '<%= WebUI.Models.WebConfigKeys.DateFormat %>';
_dateFormat = 'MM-dd-yyyy';
//var dateArray = '<%= ViewData["CompareCollectionDateSvc"] %>';
var dateArray = '07/05/2016,07/06/2016,07/07/2016,07/08/2016,07/11/2016';
dateArray = dateArray.split(',');
console.log(dateArray);
var _firstVal = dateArray[0];
console.log(_firstVal);
var _LastVal = dateArray[4];
console.log(_LastVal);
```

Comment: The error is that i am getting data from server but it is not getting assigned to variables like var dateArray or _dateFormat thats why split function is giving error as there is no data in dateArray to split.